# Representing the predicted value $\hat{Y}_h$ as a linear function of $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$

Tags: regression, self-study

A question asks me to represent $\hat{Y}_h$ as a linear function of the observations $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$.

What I have attempted:

\begin{align}
\hat{Y}_h & = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 X_h\\
& = (\overline{Y} - \hat{\beta}_1 \overline{X}) + \hat{\beta}_1 X_h\\
& = \overline{Y}  + \hat{\beta}_1 (X_h-\overline{X})\\
& = \overline{Y} - \frac{S_{xy}}{S_{xx}} (X_h - \overline{X})\\
& = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i - \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\overline{X})(Y_i-\overline{Y})}{\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-\overline{X})^2}(X_h - \overline{X})
\end{align}

From here it just seems like I've made a mess out of it. I'm not sure if this start is even correct, and if it is I'm not sure how to proceed from here. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit**

As per Dave's comment: 
$$
\hat{Y}_1 = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 X_1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad Y_1 = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1
$$
$$
\hat{Y}_2 = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 X_2 \qquad \text{and} \qquad Y_2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_2
$$
$$
\hat{Y}_3 = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 X_3 \qquad \text{and} \qquad Y_3 = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_3
$$
I figured, since $X_1 = \frac{Y_1 - \beta_0}{\beta_1}$, I can get
$$
\hat{Y}_1 = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 \frac{Y_1 - \beta_0}{\beta_1}
$$
I still seem somewhat stuck, however...

Comment: Yeah...I made a mistake. I now challenge the very idea of the problem. The whole point of regression is to have a dependence. This problem asks for an equation for a prediction that doesn’t depend on the predictor. You’re supposed to get an answer that doesn’t care if $X_h=1$ or $X_h=100$, yet $\hat{Y}_h$ most certainly does depend on the value of $X_h$. Where did you find this problem?

Comment: It was a question assigned to in my university class. While the question doesn't explicitly say so, it's possible (based on our recent discussions in class) that the intent is that $X_h$ is outside the data used to create the linear model.

Edit: My guess is that I'm looking for something in the form of $\hat{Y}_h = \sum_{i=1}^n g(Y_i) X_h$ for some function $g$.